# MFMailComposeViewController does not find local css file

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, css, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I create a html string that I send via MFMailComposeViewController as an email.

I have includes 2 css references, one local css and one server css to provide both css access for offline ipads and for any online mail clients.

```
NSString *html = @"<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN\"> \n";
html = [html stringByAppendingString:@"<html> \n"];
html = [html stringByAppendingString:@"<head> \n"];

html = [html stringByAppendingFormat:@"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"%@\"> \n", @"styles.css"];
html = [html stringByAppendingFormat:@"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"%@\"> \n", @"http://www.mydomain.com/styles.css"];

html = [html stringByAppendingString:@"</head> \n"];
```

Being online, the MFMailComposeViewController shows the email correctly (probably with the server css). Being offline, the MFMailComposeViewController does not have any css and shows only plain html email.

I have already tried to determine the path of the local css file like

```
NSString* cssPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"styles"
                                                    ofType:@"css"];

html = [html stringByAppendingFormat:@"<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"%@\"> \n", cssPath];
```

but without any success.

Local html files that reference the local css file are displayed correctly in UIWebView.

edit:
Does the html mail have access to bundle data like css or images at all? Also my tag

```
background-image:   url(image.png);
```

does not work with neither path.